# Непонятная ошибка при разборе(parse) VectorDrawable Android

Tags: android, svg

Решил использовать в своем проекте svg-файлы. Выбор мой пал на эту [библиотеку](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/)
SVG-изображения преобразовываю в xml-ресурс при помощи плагина к AndroidStudio - SVG2VectorDrawable. На выходе получается следующий xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="500" android:width="500dp" android:height="500dp">
    <group android:name="layer1" android:translateY="-552.36218" android:translateX="0">
        <path
            android:pathData="m 249.61649,554.37094 c -136.86649,0 -247.92681,111.06032 -247.92681,247.92681 0,136.8665 111.06032,247.66695 247.92681,247.66695 136.8665,0 247.66694,-110.80045 247.66694,-247.66695 0,-136.86649 -110.80044,-247.92681 -247.66694,-247.92681 z m -95.11657,98.75492 271.83589,157.4881 c -102.83575,57.01556 -160.15202,89.00467 -271.83589,157.4881 l 0,-314.9762 z"
            android:name="path3871" android:fillColor="#673AB7" android:fillAlpha="1"
            android:strokeColor="#00FFFFFF" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

В коде использую все как по примеру:

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
try
{
    SVG svg = SVG.getFromResource(this, R.drawable.vector_drawable_vector_playup);
    Drawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture());
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
catch(SVGParseException e)
{
    Log.d("Test","e: "+e.toString());
}
```

Итогом моих трудов становится такой *Exception*:

```
com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGParseException: SVG parse error: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой или просто знает ее решение, пожалуйста ответьте. Гугл и стэк уже прочитал - решения пока не нашел.

Comment: Тут либо SVG2VectorDrawable, либо AndroidSVG. Вы делаете и то и то. SVG.getFromResource ожидает натуральный svg, а не преобразованный...

Comment: Перенеси пожалуйста комментарий в ответ. Я добавил напрямую svg-файл, который поместил в директорию raw. И получилось добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека [AndroidSVG](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) работает с оригинальными svg. Поэтому преобразовывать svg файлы для использования в библиотеке нет необходимости.

Кроме того, для работы с векторными картинками (как раз преобразованными) в android есть VectorDrawableCompat из support library (начиная с 23.2). См, начиная [отсюда](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.ke/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).